# VB.NET project : dll name is not declared

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, vb6, dllimport

When i try to build my VB.NET solution, it tell me that my dll name is not declared. But I'm sure that my dll is declared and exists in the bin directory.
(the solution works on another machine, but not on mine)

[image]

[image]

Could someone help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you add a reference to that library in the project?

Comment: looks like vb6 issue

Comment: More information is needed.  Was this .dll created in VB.Net?  Are you using VB6 or VB.Net?